# when might magento Mage::getModel('customer/form'); fail?

Tags: magento

I have the following two lines of code in within a controller class.

```
        $customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
        $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
            ->setEntity($customer);
```

I am getting  "Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormCode() on a non-object in ..."
on the second of those two lines.

what might cause the first line to return a "non-object" ? (I guess it fails and returns a null but why would this happen ?)

I am not sure if this is relevant but this is happening in a site that uses the Enterprise version of magento (Magento ver. 1.8.0.0).

Comment: Look into your exeption.log, you should find some ideas there. It might happen if Mage_Customer module is disabled, you have rewrite for 'customer/form' model, or even file with Mage_Customer_Model_Form class is missing.

Comment: Is there a way to text via code what class does 'customer/form' resolve to ? so I can tell if it has been rewritten ?

Comment: Sure, `Mage::getConfig()->getModelClassName('customer/form')`.

Comment: @Zyava, you where right, the file was actually missing. please post as an answer so I will be able to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your exeption.log, you should find some ideas there. It might happen if Mage_Customer module is disabled, you have rewrite for 'customer/form' model, or even file with Mage_Customer_Model_Form class is missing.

Comment: As Sherlock Holmes said "when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth".
Yep, the file was actually missing.